# Increase timeout for Invoke-SshCommand

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

```
Powershell Errors: "Session operation has timed out" At C:\SpDrive\Moodle\Provision-MoodleLMS.ps1:108 char:2
+     Invoke-SSHCommand -ComputerName $serName -Command "$temp" -q
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-SSHCommand], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SshOperationTimeoutException,Invoke-SSHCommand
```

Is there any way to increase the session timeout for `Invoke-SSHCommand` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/issues/9), the developer has added a `-Timeout` parameter to address this in version 1.7.

Unfortunately, I cannot find this in the release notes, and all I manage to install on my own computer is version 1.6, which does not have that parameter :-/.

Comment: Even I am having the same problem. the parameter -Timeout doesnt exist in my powershell

Answer (score 0):

you can use "New-SSHSession" Like the following, and you can modify "ConnectionTimeout" as you want.

> > New-SSHSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credentials -ConnectionTimeout 5000